# dynamic parameter in jquery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, dynamic, parameters, autocomplete, runtime

I am not able to pass the parameter filter dynamically in the following code.
The filter value depends on the dropdown (id="dataLevel") value and is used to generate different suggestions for autocomplete accordingly.

### HTML CODE:

```
<td>
<select id="dataLevel" name="dataLevel" 
    onchange="enableSearch(this);resetError(this);" >
    <option value="0">-- Select Level --</option>
    <option value="1">Group Level</option>
    <option value="2">Region Level</option>
    <option value="3">Sub Region Level</option>
    <option value="4">Branch Level</option>
</select>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</td>
<td>
    <input value="" name="searchTarget" id="searchTarget" type="text" />
</td>
```

### JAVASCRIPT CODE:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#searchTarget").autocomplete(
    "/jsp/AjaxInterface.jsp",{maxItemsToShow:15,extraParams:{filter:getTargetFilter()}}
    );
});

function getTargetFilter() {
    var targetType = document.getElementById('dataLevel').value;
    switch (targetType) {
    case '1':
        return 0;
        break;
    case '2':
        return 26;
        break;
    case '3':
        return 65;
        break;
    case '4':
        return 66;
        break;
    default:
        return 0;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you defining enableSearch and resetError?

Comment: Right, but those functions are not defined anywhere. Are you using an external library? Other than breaking on that, there are no issues with your script.

Comment: those are defined but not included as irrelevant it was by mistake included

Comment: Well then there is nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: The issue is that value of filter is always 0 since initialised and not changing after changing the dataLevel combo

Comment: if  I put an alert in getTargetFilter() method it will be called only once while initializing. But I need it to be called every time I change the drop down

Comment: Which autocomplete plugin are you using? I cannot find a maxItemsToShow or extraParams option anywhere in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

You can create more control over the AJAX by using the `source` option and writing your own AJAX call.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#searchTarget").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.getJSON("/jsp/AjaxInterface.jsp", {
                term: request.term,
                filter: getTargetFilter()

            }, response);
        },
        maxItemsToShow: 15
    });
});
```

See the Mulitple-Remote demo  in API  http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple-remote and "View SOurce"

Comment: I tried the code but it has no effect. Not getting alert in getTargetFilter() function

Comment: don't know what issue is, I am able to run functions in this demo. Demo is a little buggy since I have to fake the server filtering of data but that is done with a function also  http://jsfiddle.net/EEdmu/1/

Answer (score 1):

You chould change the Filter option every time Datalevel value changes.

```
function getTargetFilter() {
        var targetType = document.getElementById('dataLevel').value;
        switch (targetType) {
        case '1':
            return 0;
            break;
        case '2':
            return 26;
            break;
        case '3':
            return 65;
            break;
        case '4':
            return 66;
            break;
        default:
            return 0;
            break;
        }
    }

    //Change filter option each time dataLever value change's
    $("#dataLevel").change(function(){
         $("#searchTarget").autocomplete("option","filter",getTargetFilter());
    });
```